# When I run the command "net statistics server" on a remote machine, it won't show the computer's name

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, command-line

So I am using Powershell. Instead of manually inputting the command to all the remote machines. I created a script that would be doing the command to all remote servers. But then, the output showed only "\"

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOVVq.png)

So what I did as a temporary fix is to instead output the machine names is to output the variable currently in the loop.

```
foreach($computer in (Get-Content "C:\servers.txt")){
    Write-host $computer -ForegroundColor yellow
    invoke-command -computername $computer -scriptblock{
        net stats server
    } 
} Write-host "Task completed" -ForegroundColor green
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you breafly explain how the output from your screenshot is generated? shouldn't it start with a yellow output? Looks loke $computer is null

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example because if I try to reproduce your problem, everything works fine. I'm sure the content of your servers.txt is invalid.

Comment: Try `foreach($computer in ((Get-Content -Path "C:\servers.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' }).Trim())) {..}` to eliminate empty lines and trim off all surrounding whitespace